# How to use libstagefright's MediaBuffer properly?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, stagefright

I:

1. Create `android::MediaBufferGroup`;
2. Fill it up with multiple `buf_group.add_buffer(new android::MediaBuffer(bufsize));` on initialisation;
3. Do `buf_group->acquire_buffer(&buffer)` when I need a buffer to send somewhere;
4. Use `buffer->data()` to get actual memory location to store the data at, use `set_range` and set up metadata, then feed the buffer into other component;
5. That other component `release`s the buffer, retuning them back to the MediaBufferGroup.

It works, but not reliably. Sometimes acquired buffer's `data()` returns NULL, sometimes the program crashes on `release()`...

How to use MediaBufferGroup properly? Should I use some synchronization?

Answer (score 0):

Almost all your steps are correct. The one point which is not clear is in step 4. Typically, `MediaBuffer` is pulled by a consumer from a producer through a `read` call. So, I presume in your setup,

1. All steps mentioned above are performed by the producer
2. Consumer invokes `mSource->read(&newBuffer);` where `newBuffer` is defined as `MediaBuffer *newBuffer`;
3. At producer's end, `MediaBuffer *mBuffer;`. The read call would be processed and output shall be populated as `*out = mBuffer;`.
4. For safety, please initialize `mBuffer` to `NULL` after this step.
5. After consuming the buffer, the consumer shall release the buffer `newBuffer->release;`
6. Again, for safety, please initialize `newBuffer` to `NULL` after this step.

With these changes, I presume your code should work fine based on your description.

Comment: Should buffer be `acquire_buffer`d in the same thread as `mSource->read` happens or it can be prepared in advance? I.e. can I acquire new buffers from one thread while other thread `release`ing old buffers?

Comment: @Vi.. As long as the references are the same, you can `acquire` and `release` the buffers across 2 threads. I presume you would store the correct reference after you have `acquire`d the same, which is then `release`d from a different thread. It may also help to use a mutex to avoid accidental simultaneous accesses.

Comment: After I moved `acquire buffer` into the `read` itself (using my own queue instead of MediaBufferGroup), it started working more or less without failures.

Comment: @Vi..Is it possible to share your code or atleast the relevant parts??

Answer (score 0):

MediaBuffer is a basic container in stagefright framework.

About the usage of MediaBuffer/MediaBufferGroup/MediaSource, There are some simple examples code under the ASOP [frameworks/av/cmds/stagefright](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/av/cmds/stagefright/).

Pay attention to the implementation of class SineSource and its usage.